# sort a struct from dir in MatLab

Tags: matlab, sorting, struct, directory, filenames

In MatLab (I got version 2014b, but I can easily update to 2015..) you got the function `dir(PATH)` from which u receive the content of a directory as a struct.

Now my Problem is, that the entries in the struct are not sorted by file name.
In my program I let the user select a file with `uigetFile` and the files are sorted by name there (done by the OS). So the user might select the first file in the dialogue but not be the first file in the `fileList`.

So my problem is, that the sort of the files in the dialogue of `uigetfile` is not the same as the function `dir` returns.

How can achieve that the struct is sorted or the files in the open-dialogue are sorted like in the struct received from `dir` ?

Here is my directory as struct in `fileList`:

```
'.'                 '22-Sep-2015 09:38:42'  0           true    736229,401875000
'..'                '17-Sep-2015 15:23:37'  0           true    736224,641400463
'JV_1914_0001.tif'  '21-Sep-2015 09:58:39'  720932      false   736228,415729167
'JV_1914_0003.tif'  '06-Mrz-2011 18:49:36'  29844547    false   734568,784444445
'JV_1914_0004.tif'  '06-Mrz-2011 18:49:44'  30382304    false   734568,784537037
'JV_1914_0005.tif'  '06-Mrz-2011 18:49:50'  30389081    false   734568,784606481
'JV_1914_0006.tif'  '06-Mrz-2011 18:49:58'  30436100    false   734568,784699074
'JV_1914_0007.tif'  '06-Mrz-2011 18:50:06'  30442889    false   734568,784791667
'JV_1914_0008.tif'  '06-Mrz-2011 18:50:14'  31125589    false   734568,784884259
'JV_1914_0009.tif'  '06-Mrz-2011 18:50:22'  31132367    false   734568,784976852
'JV_1914_0010.tif'  '06-Mrz-2011 18:50:30'  31080335    false   734568,785069444
'JV_1914_0011.tif'  '06-Mrz-2011 18:50:36'  31087112    false   734568,785138889
'JV_1914_0012.tif'  '06-Mrz-2011 18:50:44'  30237671    false   734568,785231482
'JV_1914_0013.tif'  '06-Mrz-2011 18:50:52'  30244449    false   734568,785324074
'JV_1914_0014.tif'  '06-Mrz-2011 18:51:00'  30282806    false   734568,785416667
'JV_1914_0015.tif'  '06-Mrz-2011 18:51:08'  30289585    false   734568,785509259
'JV_1914_0016.tif'  '06-Mrz-2011 18:51:16'  30294053    false   734568,785601852
'JV_1914_0017.tif'  '06-Mrz-2011 18:51:24'  30300833    false   734568,785694444
'JV_1914_0018.tif'  '06-Mrz-2011 18:51:32'  30300833    false   734568,785787037
'ccc.tif'           '08-Sep-2015 21:28:44'  23332298    false   736215,894953704
```

and as u see is the file `ccc.tif` at the end of the list while its in the dialogue of `uigetfile` on the first place (sorted by name - I guess that might be OS-specific) [image: Dialogue-for File selection]

Comment: I have never noticed `files = dir('*.txt'); files.name` not to be sorted by filename. Have you got an example?

Comment: @IKavanagh I edited my post above, you can see now the structure received from `dir` and a screenshot from the opening dialogue.

Comment: I just added a file `JV_1914_0013.1.tif` and this was on the right position in the list o.O

Comment: The list is sorted alphabetically, but MATLAB sorts capital letters before non-capitals.... So `ABC...Z` go before `abc...z` and thus`c` goes after `J`, not before. Either sort them manually by sorting the list based on the lower case file names (use `lowerCaseString = lower('anyString')`), or adapt your UI to sort it like MATLAB does. You probably want to try the first, e.g. by looping over all files in the folder and renaming them to lower case before doing any further steps or lowering the case of the list of file names and then sorting it.

Comment: Ah I see what you need. `dir`'s sorting has always been fine for me. May I ask why you need the `output` of `dir` and `uigetfile`? Maybe there is a better approach to take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In general**, I don't think MATLAB can determine how files are sorted in the `uigetfile` dialogue. At least in Windows, the user can optionally sort the dialogue by name, date, size, and type, and no information regarding the chosen sort method is returned to MATLAB.

**For your specific need**, if all you need is `ccc` to be sorted ahead of `JV...` then this may help:

`dir` returns `'ccc'` after `'JV...'` because MATLAB sorts uppercase letters before lowercase. If indeed that's your only problem:

```
files   = dir('*.txt'); 
names   = {files.name};
[~,idx] = sort(lower(names));
names   = names(idx);
```

`lower` turns everything in `names` to lowercase so that case is no longer an issue. `[~,idx]=sort()` returns the indices of the sorted case-*in*sensitive list, which you use to reorder the actual list.

Comment: nice this worked fine for me. what was missing before just was the `lower` function and I was wondering why it doesn't sort XD